# How do I replace a dataframe's columns values with another dataframe values by Id in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

There are a lot of similar questions, I tried them all but they are not working as I want them to. Let me explain:

I have two dataframes `df1` and `df2`. Shape of `df1` is `(10000,10)` and shape of `df2` is `(6000,3)` .

Sample `df1`:

```
id      col1   col2    col3
sdfge    0       43     35
fgdge    0       34     353
dfgge   500     434     345
dsggh    43     34       345
bcbnn    23      0       86
gnncn    24      0       868
iopip    0       0       687
```

Sample `df2`

```
id      col1   col2  
sdfge    3453     453  
fgdge    23      345   
dsggh    44     357   
iopip    0      886
```

Now I want to replace `col1` and `col2` value in `df1` by using values from `df2` (join by `id`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html):

```
df1['col1'] = (df1['id'].map(df2.set_index('id')['col1'])
                        .fillna(df1['col1'], downcast='infer'))
df1['col2'] = (df1['id'].map(df2.set_index('id')['col2'])
                        .fillna(df1['col2'], downcast='infer'))

print(df1)
      id  col1  col2  col3
0  sdfge  3453   453    35
1  fgdge    23   345   353
2  dfgge   500   434   345
3  dsggh    44   357   345
4  bcbnn    23     0    86
5  gnncn    24     0   868
6  iopip     0   886   687
```